# JavaScript Advanced Syntax - I don't understand

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax

So I recently copied this code from the internet to format strings inline:

```js
module.exports=function(){
    String.prototype.FormatPlus = String.prototype.FormatPlus || function(){
        "use strict";
        let str = this.toString();
        if (arguments.length) {
            let t = typeof arguments[0];
            let key;
            let args = ("string" === t || "number" === t) ? Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) : arguments[0];
            
            for (key in args) {
                str = str.replace(new RegExp("\\{" + key + "\\}", "gi"), args[key]);
            }
            
            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

I understand most of it, except this part:

```js
let args = ("string" === t || "number" === t) ? Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) : arguments[0];
```

Is there any professional JavaScript Node.js programmers that can break-down every bit of this line please?

Comment: It's frowned upon to extend the prototype of builtin objects in the first place, and this code isn't particularly well-written or complaint with modern JS standards either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t` is the type of the first argument. So the ternary conditional expression tests whether the first argument is a string or number.

If it is, `arguments` is converted to an array by calling `Array.prototype.slice()`, and this is assigned to `args`.

If not, the first argument is assigned to `args`.

This can be written more clearly, using modern EcmaScript 6 features:

```
let args;
if (t === 'string' || t == 'number') {
    args = [...arguments];
} else {
    args = arguments[0];
}
```

The purpose of this is to allow the caller to provide the values to be formatted as a single array or object, or spread as separate arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`arguments` is an array type.  if first element of `argument` array is of type `string` or `number` then you are just returning entire `argument` array itself by calling `slice` method of Array & assigning it to `args`.

If first element of `argument` is not of type `string` or `number` then you are returning just first element of `argument` & assigning it to `args`.

`?` is [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) in javascript which is similar to `if.else` block.

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object.

In the function you provided, `t` is an alias for `typeof arguments[0]`.

So in your code, when the first element of `arguments` is a string or a number, you `call` the `Array.prototype.slice()` function on **every** element.

For example, if `arguments[0]` is the string `"hello world"`, `Array.prototype.slice.call("hello world")` would return `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']`.